# Tableau could not receive data from server: Software caused connection abort

Tags: windows, postgresql, database-connection, tableau-api

I have a Tableau (reporting) server on Windows 10 that internally uses PostgresDB. Besides I have a PostgresDB, where my data is located, so reports are aggregated using this data.

*What should our end-user experience?* - He or she opens in a web browser a report by url and see the data.

For some reason from time to time our end-users face with the problem:

> could not receive data from server: Software caused connection abort
>   (0x00002745/10053) Unable to connect to the server "server_name".
>   Check that the server is running and that you have access privileges
>   to the requested database.

This problem arises with different reports and in different time. Moreover, when I do not fix it for a long time, this report may start to work again.

There is no firewall or antivirus on Windows where Tableau server is, but there is a VPN.

**What has helped?**

Pgbouncer has solved it problem partially. By partially I mean that during 2 weeks of exploitation this error has only once occurred instead of 3 times per day by using pure Postgres.

Restart of Tableau server solves this problem as well.

Accidental loose of Internet connection on Tableau server also may help with this problem.

**What have I also checked?**

1) When everything is fine, in Pgbouncer logs I can see that queries are loading when I interact with a report, otherwise (when there is this error) no logs are recorded. So Tableau Postgres can't connect to Postgres with data for some reasons.

2) When I connect manually to PostgresDB from the Tableau Postgres, then everything is fine and all queries were executed, while end-clients face with the problem interacting via web browser.

3) When I type in `CMD` in Tableau Server (windows): `netstat -nao | find PostgresDB:5432`, in normal case I see many TCP connections with different PIDs except one PID which is executed from 2 different ports on Tableau Server, however all of them are tabprotosrv.exe; in case when it fails I see only one PID which is executed from 2 different ports on Tableau Server.

**So I have 2 main questions**
1. How to solve it normally?
2. Or what should I check else?